# concatenating and Indexing highest values by grouped columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

Hello guys I hope you are doing great I have the following dataset,

I have the following dataset:

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 | A7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1.2650612 | -0.6868529 | -0.4456620 | 1.2240818 | 0.3598138 | 0.4007715 | 0.1106827 |

```
colnames<-c(paste0(1:7,"A"))
set.seed(123)
values<-c(rnorm(7))
```

I want to be able to create a code that will find the highest value (row-wise)found within the first 3 columns (A1,A2,A3) and write the corresponding column name, repeat the same for the following 2 columns and the same for the remaining 2 columns (A6,A7), if all values are the same (maybe it can happen then just write the name of the first columns withint the group)

mu desired output will be:

| A1,A2,A3 | A4,A5 | A6,7 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A3 | A4 | A5 |

Thank you gusy so much, I will be very attending to reward the ans to whom can helpe me!

Comment: Just one row or is your real data multiple rows?

Comment: Hello Gregor it has multiple rows! thanks for your interets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, everything()) %>%
  group_by(group = rep(1:3, c(3, 2, 2))) %>% 
  summarise(name1 = name[which.max(value)],
   name2 = toString(name)) %>% 
 select(name2, name1) %>% 
 deframe %>% 
 as_tibble_row
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  `A1, A2, A3` `A4, A5` `A6, A7`
  <chr>        <chr>    <chr>   
1 A3           A4       A6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A1 = -1.2650612, A2 = -0.6868529, A3 = -0.445662, 
    A4 = 1.2240818, A5 = 0.3598138, A6 = 0.4007715, A7 = 0.1106827), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Im so sorry akrun I did not mark your perfect answer earlier I just went back to this post so sorry you were excellent! 10/10